# How to convert type System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection to string[]

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Some functions in my class library accepts `string[]` as parameter.

I want to convert my `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection` to `string[]`.

Is it possible with some one liner or I have to create array with loop?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use [StringCollection.CopyTo(string[],index)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection.copyto.aspx) to copy the contents to string array. **This is supported in all .Net frameworks.**

```
System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection sc = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();
sc.Add("Test");
sc.Add("Test2");

string[] strArray = new string[sc.Count];
sc.CopyTo(strArray,0);
```

Answer (score 32):

Try this

```
System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection strs = new  System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();
strs.Add("blah"); 
strs.Add("blah"); 
strs.Add("blah"); 

string[] strArr = strs.Cast<string>().ToArray<string>();
```

Comment: `strs.Cast<string>().ToArray();` is enough. You don't have to cast to string again in `ToArray`

Comment: @Habib: There is no difference between `.ToArray<string>()` and `.ToArray()` apart from the number of key strokes when entered.

Answer (score 10):

This does the trick:

```
System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection sc = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();
/*sc.Add("A");
sc.Add("B");*/
string[] asArray = sc.Cast<string>().ToArray();
```

Disclaimer: I have no idea what the performance characteristics of this are.